# Google AppEngine Blobstore Video Streaming in Html Template

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, video-streaming, blobstore

i managed to get the code from the following link to work. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Complete_Sample_App

When I upload a video I managed to get the video to stream on my browser but my question is how to I place the video in my html template?

Comment: You can use HTML video player with its ***src*** attribute as the serve url for you video location.

Comment: Ok I managed to get it to work but what I really dont understand is what does send_blob(blob_info) does and what it returns. I cant seem to find the documentation for it.

Comment: The answer provided was not really what i was asking for. But it been so long, that i've already found the answer myself

Answer (score 2):

In order to display they uploaded video you can either use the [html video tag](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/) or one of the media player solutions that are available out there and will give you apart from a delicate player, cross browser compatibility along with a Flash fallback. Here is a great [list](http://praegnanz.de/html5video/) of media players that you can use. I have used for my personal projects [mediaelementjs](http://mediaelementjs.com/) and I am really satisfied with ease of use and stability of performance.